# Merging/extending records with identical type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having problems with merging records of identical types with a consecutive sequence and calculating the full sequence from the merged records.

The ordering should be done on the basis ID as the sequences might rollover to 0 when they reach 100. See last entry in input/output example.

Is it possible to have an input as listed below and have a query that produces the output which is also listed below in SQL Server 2012?

Input

```
Id     Type     Begin     End
-----------------------------
1      1        10        20
2      1        21        23
3      2        24        28
4      1        29        40
5      2        41        47
6      2        48        50
7      2        75        80
8      1        81        100
9      1        0         10
10     1        11        20
11     1        21        5
12     1        5         6
```

Output

```
FromId     ToId     Type     Begin     End    Length
----------------------------------------------------
1          2        1        10        23     13 (23-19)
3          3        2        24        28     4  (28-24)
4          4        1        29        40     11 (40-29)
5          6        2        41        50     9  (50-41)
7          7        2        75        80     5  (80 - 75)
8          12       1        81        20     227*
```

*(100-81) + 10 + (100-11 + 20) + (100-21 + 5) + 1 -> *rolloverS of seq*

### EDIT

Please note that rows 6 and 7 from the source are *not* merged because they are not consecutive. Row 6 ends with 50 and row 7 starts with 75.  Only consecutive rows with the same type need to be merged.

Comment: What is the [Type] veriety in the context of the task? Is it [1..2] or it is an INT?

Comment: it is an int which (now) can only hold the values 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can typically be solved with a recursion like this:

```
create table #t ([Id] int, [Type] int, [Begin] int, [End] int);
insert into #t values (1,1,10,20),(2,1,21,23),(3,2,24,28),(4,1,29,40),
(5,2,41,47),(6,2,48,50),(7,2,75,80),(8,1,81,100),(9,1,0,10),(10,1,10,20);

with cRek as (
    -- records with no followup
    select  t.[Type], FromId = t.[Id], ToId = t.[Id], 
            t.[Begin], t.[End], [Length] = t.[End]-t.[Begin]+1
    from    #t t
    left join #t tf
        on  tf.[Type] = t.[Type]
        and tf.[Begin] = (t.[End]+1)%101
        and tf.[Id] > t.[Id]
    where   tf.[Id] is null

    union all

    -- previous record
    select  t.[Type], FromId = t.[Id], ToId = tf.[ToId], 
            t.[Begin], tf.[End], [Length] = tf.[Length]+t.[End]-t.[Begin]+1
    from    #t t
    inner join cRek tf
        on  tf.[Type] = t.[Type]
        and tf.[Begin] = (t.[End]+1)%101
        and tf.[FromId] > t.[Id]
)
select  *
from    cRek r
where   FromId = 
        (select min(x.FromId)
        from    cRek x
        where   x.[Type]=r.[Type] and x.[ToId]=r.[ToId])
order by ToId;

drop table #t;
```

Your sample has some minor flaws:

- 100 is followed up by 0 therefore you have 101 distinct elements (modulo 101!)
- Id 10 is no follow-up to Id 9 because they both include element 10
- The length from 10 to 23 is 14 because it is an including interval

HTH, Manfred

Comment: this one works _almost_ the problem i have now is that the length (total duration) field isn't properly calculated if the sequence rolls over (multiple times).

Comment: it should - there is just an issue if you have a rollover within one Id. That's the reason why I add the lengths calculated within the single Ids.

Comment: i tried the query in sql fiddle but got some errors; please check this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcfb1/2/0

Comment: I seem to have found the problem :) - The length field shouldn't always be End - Begin because if the sequence rolls over it should be (Max sequence (=100) - Begin) + End. This resolves the problem of wrong durations.

Answer (score 3):

You last row have Begin = 10 which is not follow the same rule with others. I update it 11 in my example. Hope this will help.

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7b50/1)

```
WITH typeRowNum AS (  
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id ASC) AS rownum
  FROM tblType
)
,rw AS (
  SELECT t1.*, 
    CASE WHEN t1.[type] = t2.[type] and ( t1.[Begin] = t2. [end] + 1 OR t1.[Begin] + 100 = t2.[end])
      THEN -1 
      ELSE t1.rownum 
    END AS group_id
  FROM typeRowNum t1
  LEFT JOIN typeRowNum t2 
    ON t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1
 )
, cte AS (
SELECT *,
  new_end = ISNULL(
    (SELECT MIN(rownum) - 1 FROM rw r2 WHERE r2.rownum > r1.rownum and r2.group_id > r1.group_id),
    (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM rw)
  )
FROM rw r1
WHERE r1.group_id > 0
 )
select 
  c1.id,c1.type,c1.[begin],c2.[end]
 ,[length] = (SELECT SUM((r.[end]  - r.[Begin]
                  + CASE WHEN r.[end] < r.[Begin] THEN 100 ELSE 0 END 
                  + CASE WHEN (r.group_id = -1) AND (r.[Begin] < r.[End]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                 ) 
             FROM rw r WHERE r.rownum  BETWEEN c1.[rownum] AND c2.[rownum])  
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN rw c2
  ON c1.new_end = c2.rownum
```

**UPDATE:** If you have NULL value, most likely you have some discontinued value in [Id] Column. Instead, you can use Row_Number to JOIN. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Pretty nice, but I would use modulo 100 in order to get all cases covered. When you'll get t1.begin=100 and t2.end=100 it will fail to show a connection.

Comment: This works fairly well _but_ (sorry) because the the total sequence can rollover multiple times. This case currently isn't covered :( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fa0d/1

Comment: @EricZ, i'm getting some strange null results with larger sets; similar to what yaugen mentions below. I need to investigate this.

Comment: @Frank, if you have null result, most likely it mean your [Id] column not always in sequance. Please check my updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

hm... very interesting task
I have ended up with the following results

```
Type    IntervalBegin   CurrEnd
1   10  20
1   NULL    23
2   24  28
1   29  40
2   41  47
2   NULL    50
2   75  80
1   81  100
1   NULL    10
1   10  20
```

but I am still puzzled about aggregating recieved results...

the query is below

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ([Id] INT, [Type] INT, [Begin] INT, [End] INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable([Id], [Type], [Begin], [End] )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10, 20),
    (2, 1, 21, 23),
    (3, 2, 24, 28),
    (4, 1, 29, 40),
    (5, 2, 41, 47),
    (6, 2, 48, 50),
    (7, 2, 75, 80),
    (8, 1, 81, 100),
    (9, 1, 0, 10),
    (10, 1, 10, 20)

    SELECT 
        [Type],
        CASE
            WHEN ShouldCompareWithPrevious = 1 AND PrevBegin IS NULL THEN CurrBegin 
            WHEN ShouldCompareWithPrevious = 1 AND PrevEnd = 100 AND CurrBegin = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN ShouldCompareWithPrevious = 1 AND PrevEnd + 1 <> CurrBegin THEN CurrBegin
            WHEN ShouldCompareWithPrevious = 0 THEN CurrBegin 
            ELSE NULL
        END IntervalBegin,
        CurrEnd
    FROM
    (

        SELECT t1.[Id], t2.[Id] t2Id,
            t1.[Type], t2.[Type] t2Type,
            (
                CASE
                 WHEN t2.[Type]  IS NULL THEN 0
                 WHEN t2.[Type] = t1.[Type] THEN 1
                 ELSE
                    0
                END
            ) AS ShouldCompareWithPrevious, 
            t1.[Begin] CurrBegin,
            t1.[End] CurrEnd,
            t2.[Begin] PrevBegin, 
            t2.[End] PrevEnd
        FROM @MyTable t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @MyTable t2
            ON t1.Id = t2.Id + 1
    ) intermideate
```